# Draw a line with circles and labels aligned under

Tags: html, css

I needed an arrow with circles on it and labels under it. I managed to hack together [current solution](https://codepen.io/sjurgis/pen/jOvWzqm) based on some other post here (can't find at the moment), but I keep having trouble aligning text labels under circles.

I've tried placing text directly on the div and then playing with negative margins to no avail. As far as I understand the whole problem stems from trying to use table borders for drawing.

Edit: IIRC I cannot use pseudo elements `:before` as part of my framework limitations...

Please ignore other imperfections as they depend on the framework I use (Salesforce's LWC) - instead,

```css
.timeline {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.circle.todo {
    border: 0.4rem solid gray;
}
.line.todo {
    border-bottom: 1.5rem solid gray;
}
.circle-contain, .line {
    display: table-cell;
}
.circle-contain {
    width: 1px;
}
.circle {
    margin: -0.2em;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 1rem;
}
.line.last {
    width: 3rem;
}
.line.last.arrow {
    border: solid transparent;
    content: "";
    pointer-events: none;
    border-left-color: gray;
    border-width: 35px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    /*margin-right: -2rem;*/
}
.label {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; margin-right: -1.5rem;">
        <div style="display: flex;">
            <div style="height: 5rem; width: 100%;">
                <div class="timeline">
                    <div class="line first todo"></div>
                    <div class="circle-contain">
                        <div class="circle todo">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line todo"></div>
                    <div class="circle-contain">
                        <div class="circle todo">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line todo"></div>
                    <div class="circle-contain">
                        <div class="circle todo">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line todo"></div>
                    <div class="circle-contain">
                        <div class="circle todo">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line todo"></div>
                    <div class="circle-contain">
                        <div class="circle todo">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="line last todo"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="line last arrow todo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline"
             style="padding-top: 0.5rem; padding-right: 7rem;">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="circle-contain label">
                section 1
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="circle-contain label">
                section 2
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="circle-contain label">
                section 3
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="circle-contain label">
                section 4
            </div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="circle-contain label">
                section 5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm searching for ways to align labels based - perhaps based on some hint/indicator/pointer on sibling element. I'm not familiar if this is possible with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I see you use `display:flex` for `.timeline` container and I'm more familiar with `flex`, so I demo u a sample with `flex` and it could be more simple in terms of HTML structure and flexible in terms of UI responsive.

Full `flex` reference over here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

For **label always under circle**, my approach is using `position:absolute` on the label and put `position:relative` to its container so that the label will always stick to the circle, and the label could be positioning further afterward based on your preference at the same time.

Hope it helps and happy coding !

```css
.timeline {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
.line.todo {
  height: 2rem;
  border-bottom: 1.5rem solid gray;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.line.todo.last {
  width: 2rem;
}
.line.todo.arrow {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 2rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2rem solid transparent;
  border-left: 2rem solid gray;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.circle-contain {
  position: relative;
}
.circle-contain .label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  /* either use 'white-space' or 'width' */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* width: 100px; */
}
.circle {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle.todo {
  border: 0.4rem solid gray;
  margin: 5px -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="line first todo"></div>
  <div class="circle-contain">
    <div class="circle todo"></div>
    <div class="label">
      section 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line todo"></div>
  <div class="circle-contain">
    <div class="circle todo"></div>
    <div class="label">
      section 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line todo"></div>
  <div class="circle-contain">
    <div class="circle todo"></div>
    <div class="label">
      section 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line todo"></div>
  <div class="circle-contain">
    <div class="circle todo"></div>
    <div class="label">
      section 4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line todo"></div>
  <div class="circle-contain">
    <div class="circle todo"></div>
    <div class="label">
      section 5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line todo last"></div>
  <div class="line todo arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rubber duck debugging at it's best - I've came up with very similar solution on my own earlier. Will post it later.